# Is it feasible to create a survey website like lime survey?

Tags: web-applications, saas, survey, surveymonkey, limesurvey

How should I go about creating a survey website, is it possible for a single individual to create a saas like surveymonkey in a reasonable time span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a website that can record user data, you cannot just use front-end development.
It might take a while, as you would first need to get a server on which your data could be stored, and then you would have to write a program in PHP or some other server-side programming language to record the data. Next, you would have to create a front-end (client-side) webpage to submit the responses. Also, you would need to consider security and other requirements.
In summary: it would take a while. You would be able to get it done better with a team.